# How can a native code in android be converted for Windows and ios using React Native

Tags: react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, native-code

I have made an android app and want to use the code for the development of the same app in windows and ios. How can I do that using React Native?
Is there any other way for the same(other than react native).

Answer (score 1):

With React Native your application logic is written and runs in JavaScript, whereas your application UI is fully native; therefore you have none of the compromises typically associated with HTML5 
UI.
Source(https://www.raywenderlich.com/126063/react-native-tutorial)

Purejs act as a connector between native components of ios and android(recently also tied up with Universal Windows Platform) So almost most of the code is reusable. Other options available are MeteorJS(WebView),PhoneGap,Titanium.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert it to Windows and iOS. All the code which you wrote in Java for Android should be rewritten for iOS and Windows. If it is in React Native, It will work directly.